# How do I change my Wan I.P with a modern day moden?

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

I have been trying to change my I.P from my I.S.P many times.

1) I have tried resetting my modem , leaving it sit for a while then plugging it back in.

2) I have now changed the lease time to 30 minutes.

By changing the lease time to 30 minutes, will that reset my DHCP in 30 minutes?

Does anyone know how to do this, without having to contact your Provider?

I believe my I.P to be Dynamic.

Comment: "By changing the lease time to 30 minutes, will that reset my DHCP in 30 minutes".  If you have a lease time of 30 minutes, your dhcp client will attempt to renew the lease every 15 minutes.  However, it will (normal circumstances) renew its existing least for 30 minutes; not request and accept a new IPv4 address.

Comment: Change the MAC address of your router. Most router allow you to spoof the MAC address.

Answer (score 3):

You may not be able to do this, as your ISP ultimately dictates how IP addresses are assigned - so if you want to change it, you should call your ISP and fight your way through to someone who understands this stuff to tell you how to do it on their network.

IP addresses are most often assigned either by MAC address (in which case you need to change your device - or at least its MAC addresses - maybe swap your modem with a friend - even better if they use a different ISP ) or by PPP negotiation - in which case this normally means you can't do anything on your side because the ISP is assigning the IP address based on your authentication username.

Further, because most devices are "always on" the advantages to an ISP of assigning your IP out of a pool [ rather then statically ] are very small, so they are probably not doing it - and even if they are, they are most likely recording the last IP address you used and trying to reserve it for your use.  IF THEY ARE DOING THIS, LEAVING YOUR MODEM OFF A LONG TIME MAY GIVE YOU A NEW IP - but we are talking at least a day, probably much more in most cases.

If you want a new apparent IP address, go  out and acquire a VPN service.  In that way the apparent IP address will be that of the VPN rather then your ISP.  Expect to pay for this though - both in dollars and slightly reduced performance.

Alternatively, change your ISP !  That will most likely mean you get a new IP address.

Comment: Some ISPs also assign the addresses by physical port – at least with ADSL, for example, they _know_ which customer you are.